# Windows Environment and Mobile-Web Applications

Tags: javascript, .net, windows, mobile, web

We offer a client-server product that runs on Windows Server (2008 R2) and SQL Server (2008 R2).
Our server is implemented via .NET 4.0 and C#.

We're looking to develop a new application that in the background will read and write from the server & DB.

The application should run on desktop, laptops, iOS devices, Android devices and Black Berry devices.

The application is targeted for a technical use (operators, technicians, installers) so rich UI is not a must at all.

What would be the best frameworks & platforms to use o achieve such an application (server side, js library, ui, etc.)

Thanks,
Janiv Ratson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can do it with a web app that would be my first choice. The reason is that the web app will run on all devices.

If web app is not possible for some reason you should go with native, .NET would probably be a good choice, it covers windows, Linux and Mac (via mono) and also you can use mono touch and mono for android to port it to iphone and android.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already work with .NET on Windows, you could cover desktops, laptops with .NET or Mono. Porting to iOS and Android with MonoTouch should not be too difficult especially if you don't have elaborate UI. I have no idea about BlackBerry though.